# NSViewController with/without nib

Tags: appkit, nsviewcontroller

I’m adding an `NSViewController` subclass to a library and trying to have my cake and eat it too.

> The default implementation of MyViewController()   (  Or init()   )
>   throws an exception

if it can’t find itself in a nib or storyboard. In order to overcome this I must `override loadView()`  and create and assign a view in code. What I really want to do is both, create a view in the code, but only have that code run in the event that the super’s implementation doesn’t find one in a nib.  I tried a

```
    do  {
        super.loadView()
        }
    catch{
        //viewCreatingCode
        }
```

But unfortunately loadView is not marked as throws so the catch doesn’t work.  Any ideas?

Comment: See how `super.loadView()` finds the view and do the same. If you can find the view, call `super.loadView()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what you're going to want to do.

`NSViewController` has three properties you want to inspect: `nibBundle`, `nibName`, and `storyboard`. All three of these properties are optional, and they're set before `loadView` is called.

The default implementation of `loadView` checks to see if these properties are set. If so, it'll initialize the view from that nib or storyboard. Otherwise, it creates an empty `NSView`.

In your implementation of `loadView`, you'll want to check these values too. If `nibName` and `storyboard` are both `nil`, you can create and set up the view how you'd like.

```
override func loadView() {
    guard nibName == nil, storyboard == nil else {
        super.loadView()
        return
    }
    view = MyCustomView()
}
```